# Spring Security -- registration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I use this template https://github.com/hellokoding/registration-login-spring-xml-maven-jsp-mysql for registration.

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = POST)
public String registration(@ModelAttribute("userForm") User userForm) {
    userService.add(userForm);
    securityService.autologin(userForm.getUsername(), userForm.getPassword());
    return "redirect:/notes/";
}
```

**method autologin:**

```
@Override
public void autologin(final String username, final String password) {
    UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, password, userDetails.getAuthorities());

    authenticationManager.authenticate(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);

    if (usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.isAuthenticated()) {
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
    }
}
```

**method loadUserByUsername:**

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userRepository.findByName(username);

    Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = user.getRoles().stream().map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName())).collect(Collectors.toSet());

    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), grantedAuthorities);
}
```

**http config:**

```
<http auto-config="true" >
    <intercept-url pattern="/notes**" access="authenticated" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/auth**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/accessDenied" access="permitAll" />

    <access-denied-handler error-page="/accessDenied" />

    <logout logout-success-url="/auth/login?logout"  />
    <form-login
            default-target-url="/notes/"
            login-page="/auth/login"
            login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password"
    />
    <remember-me data-source-ref="dataSource" />

    <session-management session-fixation-protection="newSession" >
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
    </session-management>
</http>
```

But, when I create an account, after 'sign up' page, I go to the 'sign in' page. And this user is added to the db. But, I must to be redirected: /notes/.

Comment: Remove the `default-target-url` and add some [AuthenticationSuccessHandler](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AuthenticationSuccessHandler.html) to do the redirection based on who is connected (ie. the Principal)

Comment: I do that, but I have same effect. I also try to change return in the controller, to "redirect:/NotesWeb/notes/", but that is also not change anything.

Comment: I don't see what `NotesWeb` has to do in here. And you changed your question, now you want a redirect to `/notes`? Maybe `usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.isAuthenticated()` is false, so not authenticated so login page (you should see that in the application logs)

Comment: I changed question, because I forgot, that I removed in notes path {username}. In application logs I don't see any issues or exceptions, only sql requests. I compare passwords, saw username and authorities, and it was all fine.

Comment: I noticed that after the `authenticationManager.authenticate(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);` I'm trying either to do `System.out.println(1);` or to exit the program, and the lines are simply not processed

Comment: @RC. if it helps me, I get the logs from log4j. http://pastebin.com/FnmJjBAm Аfter the first line, there is an implementation of authorization in spring security. Then, show the result, but it is not present (penultimate line). The last line is executed the login method in the controller that not should be performed.

Answer (score 0):

AuthenticationManager's `authenticate(Authentication auth)` method returns a newly created Authentication object, not the one you are passing as parameter modified.

The `autologin()` method actually is doing more things that it should. I would try like this:

```
public void autologin(final String username, final String password) {
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = 
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        username, password);

        Authentication authResult = authenticationManager.authenticate(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);

        if (authResult.isAuthenticated()) {
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
        }

    }
```

When you call `AuthenticationManager.authenticate(Authentication auth)` the AuthenticationManager is itself trying the authenticaion process against every Authentication class matching AuthenticationProvider, which itself must call the `UserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(String username)`.

So calling first the `UserDetailsService` bypassing the AuthenticationManager/AuthenticationProvider structure, and then retrying to authenticate the Authentication object created using the UserDetails from the service against the Manager/Provider/UserDetailsService is a bit annoying for me.

Please try my "autologin" snippet instead of yours to see if it works

Comment: I try your 'autologin', but I don't know works it or not. When I click to Sign Up on the JSP, I must redirected to /notes/, but go to the Sign In JSP page.

And it's normally, that after method 'authenticate', the lines are not processed. i.e. I try to output some information, but it ignores.